# UK app that counts rent payments towards credit score

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-score, rent

I live in the UK.

A few months ago, I saw in the tube an add for a app that allowed users to count their rent payments towards their credit scores.

I wasn't interested at that time, but now I want to increase my credit score.

Do you know that app, or other ways I can use my rent payments to build my credit score?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the Rental Exchange Scheme and the CreditLadder app. Full details are [here](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/mortgages/rental-exchange-scheme/), note they are potentially out of date so you might want to do your own research about CreditLadder before continuing.

Comment: Hmmm, I think it was a different app, but this does what I want as well. Do you know people that use it? Did they have trouble with their landlords? I says on their website `CreditLadder reserve the right to perform identification (ID) checks on you and your landlord. Furthermore, CreditLadder reserve the right to perform Land Registry checks to verify property ownership.` Can this annoy the landlord and make them unwilling to renew the rent?

Comment: They would only know about the Land Registry check if they have an email alert set up with them, and even then it is an open registry - anybody can pay a small fee to see the ownership record for a property. The ID checks may be another matter!

Comment: I see, yes, that makes sense.